# Python: Read a file separated strictly on 0x0a, not '\n' string

Tags: python

I need to read a huge (larger than memory) unquoted TSV file. Fields may contain the string "\n". However, python tries to be clever and split that string in two. So for example a row containing:

```
cat    dog    fish\nchips    4.50
```

gets split into two lines:

```
['cat', 'dog', 'fish']
['chips', 4.5]
```

What I want is a single line:

```
['cat', 'dog', 'fish\nchips', 4.5]
```

How can I make python stop being clever and just split lines on 0x0a?

My code is:

```
with open(path, 'r') as file:
    for line in file:                   
        row = line.split("\t")
```

Quoting the TSV file is not an option since I don't create it myself.

Comment: `\n` **is** the `\x0a` byte.

Comment: The string "\n" is the string "\n". That's what I see when I open the file in any other program.

Comment: Python will **not** see a literal ``\`` followed by a literal `n` character as a newline.

Comment: Are you sure your file contains the two-character digraph '\' + 'n' and not a literal newline? Your code works for me.

Comment: Can you upload enough of the file to some hosting site for us to see the problem?

Comment: Well, I tried opening this using csv.reader and it complained that there was a "\n" in an unquoted field, and to use universal line breaks - which I don't want because I don't want it to split on it. This version with `for line in file` does the same thing, so it must be...

Comment: @jbrown: Then perhaps the other program expects `\r\n` as newline separators and **displays** single `\n` characters as an escape code?

Comment: What "any other program"s did you try opening the file in?

Comment: If the lines are separated by `\n` and an unquoted field contains `\n` how is a simple line reader supposed to magically deduce when an `\n` is a new line or "part of a field"? You would need extra character-by-character (or field-by-field) logic to handle such malformed data.

Comment: @lvo because fields contain the *string* \n ('\' + 'n'). that's the whole problem (or seems to be)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This already works correctly; for a file with a literal `\` followed by a literal `n` character (two bytes), will **never** be seen by Python as a newline.

What you have, then, is a single `\n` character, an actual newline. The *rest* of your file is separated by the `\r\n` Windows conventional line separator.

Use [`io.open()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/io.html#io.open) to control how newlines are to be treated:

```
import io

with io.open(path, newline='\r\n') as infh:
    for line in infh:
        row = line.strip().split('\t')
```

Demo:

```
>>> import io
>>> with open('/tmp/test.txt', 'wb') as outfh:
...     outfh.write('cat\tdog\tfish\nchips\t4.50\r\nsnake\tegg\tspam\nham\t42.38\r\n')
...
>>> with io.open('/tmp/test.txt', newline='\r\n') as infh:
...     for line in infh:
...         row = line.strip().split('\t')
...         print row
... 
[u'cat', u'dog', u'fish\nchips', u'4.50']
[u'snake', u'egg', u'spam\nham', u'42.38']
```

Note that `io.open()` also decodes your file data to unicode; you may need to specify an explicit encoding for non-ASCII file data.

Comment: And let's hope there can't be CR characters embedded in the fields too, since then the file is ambiguous (although possibly still recoverable if the data is supposed to be sufficiently regular).

Comment: @SteveJessop: Indeed, in which case the OP should produce properly-quoted CSV and use the `csv` module.

Comment: Well, it may not be possible to produce properly-quoted CSV if the data source is impervious to bug reports.

Answer (score 1):

If your problem is .readline() and splitting on \t, try using the csv builtin:

```
import csv

with open(path, 'r') as file: 
    reader = csv.Reader(file, delimiter='\t') # Or DictReader - I like DictReader. 
    reader.next()
```

It handles these things for us.

Comment: The CSV reader will still see the newline the OP has as a newline. This is a case of misunderstanding the input data, not of how it is read.

Comment: Oh good point - I was imagining a world where OP had a bunch of tab-delimited data and didn't care about newlines. But that'd have made one fairly long row.